# Future proof stripe method

Tags: javascript, php

I am a stripe user but because the volume of sales that will be generated during the projects first two years we will be eventually migrating our billing away from stripe to direct merchant accounts with our primary financial institution.

To allow for that transition down the road while still continuing to use stripe in the early beta state we are going to use stripes connect button but we are going to store the credit card data entered by the end user into our own PCI compliant database. Below is the code I have currently. How can I make this attaché the values from the js POST request to the sever POST request as well.

```
<script>
    $('#stripe').submit(function() {
        var params = [{ 
            name: "description", 
            value: document.forms[0].stripe.data-description 
        }];
        $.each(params, function(i, param) {
            $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                .attr('name', param.name)
                .attr('value', param.value)
                .appendTo('#stripe');
        });
        return true;
    });
</script>

<form action="" method="post" id="stripe">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="xxxxxxxxxxx"
        data-name="IA / USA Holdings"
        data-description="Investment"
        data-amount="1000000"
        data-currency="USD"
        data-allow-remember-me="false"
        data-panel-label="Pay {{amount}} USD"
        data-label="Pay"  
        data-billingAddress="false"
        data-zip-code="false">
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see any code below.

Comment: Do not use the default embedded form but use a custom form and hook in to the submit function to send your post request to the database server. This is explained in detail https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms

Comment: I have a js fiddle URL above

Comment: Ive updated my current code above. - Any suggestions on this verion?